# Copy files with patterns to different folders

Tags: shell, directory, cp

In a directory I have the following files:

> lebron_2018.txt lebron_2019.txt
>
> melo_2018.log melo_2019_01.log
>
> wade_2018.bak wade_2019_02.jpg

All the files has delimiter of "_", I would like to copy the files to different new directory according to the prefix. For example

> lebron_2018.txt lebron_2019.txt will copy to \backup\lebron
>
> melo_2018.log melo_2019_01.log will copy to \backup\melo
>
> wade_2018.bak wade_2019_02.jpg will copy to \backup\wade

I can do it by cp lebron*.* \backup\lebron.
But can it be done by searching the filename, and copy to the folder according to their filename automatically?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Sort files into multiple directories based on filename?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/549259/sort-files-into-multiple-directories-based-on-filename)

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 0):

Lots of nice ideas in @AdminBee linked post but it just feels right to execute a loop only for each pattern that can be `glob`bed.

Assuming no whitespace:

```
for f in $(ls *_*.txt | cut -d_ -f1 | uniq); do
    mkdir -p ./backup/$f;
    cp $f_*.txt ./backup/$f/;
done
```

Answer (score 0):

Your slashes are going the wrong way for a *nix system.
Should work as long as you have no spaces or exotic characters in the file names.

```
for FILE in *_*.txt ; do
  DIR="/backup/${FILE//_*}"
  mkdir -p "${DIR}" || continue
  mv "${FILE}" "${DIR}"
done
```

Uses bash variable expansion to snip the name off the file to make the directory.
Plays safe by skipping items where it can’t create the directory (to prevent data loss).